Number of real roots of a specific polynomial
I am working with the following polynomial:
$f_n := (x^2 + 2(n − 1)) \cdot (x − 2) \cdot (x − 4) \cdot (x-6) \cdots (x − 2(n − 2)) − 2$; $n\ge3$
I had to show that $f_n$ has exactly $n-2$ real roots.
To this end, I used the Intermediate Value Theorem and the sign of functions at odd natural numbers.
For example, $f_9 = (x^2+16)(x-2)(x-4)(x-6)(x-8)(x-10)(x-12)(x-14)-2$
We can construct a table and observe the sign change:
\begin{array}{c|cccccccc|c}
  & x^2+16 & (x-2) & (x-4) & (x-6) & (x-8) & (x-10) & (x-12) & (x-14) & \text{sign} \\
\hline
f(<2) & + & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
f(3)  & + & + & - & - & - & - & - & - & + \\
f(5)  & + & + & + & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
f(7)  & + & + & + & + & - & - & - & - & + \\
f(9)  & + & + & + & + & + & - & - & - & - \\
f(11) & + & + & + & + & + & + & - & - & + \\
f(13) & + & + & + & + & + & + & + & - & - \\
f(>14)& + & + & + & + & + & + & + & + & + \\
\end{array}
The sign changes 7 times, so we have 7 zeroes.
In general, we have $n-2$ relevant factors for the sign of the function, therefore $n-2$ sign changes and $n-2$ roots.
But I was wondering if there was a simpler way of thinking about this problem.
If you simply ignore the $-2$ in $f_n$, we have just the polynomial
$q_n := (x^2 + 2(n − 1)) · (x − 2) · (x − 4) . (x-6) · · · (x − 2(n − 2))$
The polynomial is already in the form of its complete factorization in $\mathbb{Z}$ and we can see that the real roots of $q_n$ will be $2, 4, 6, ..., 2(n-2)$, while the roots of $x^2 + 2(n − 1)$ will be the remaining complex ones.
Dealing with the derivative of $f_n$ is utterly impractical for small values of $n$ already. So, my (a little naive) question is: is there any other general way to evaluate this interference from the constant term?
$x^3+5x^2+3x+2$ has one real root, while $x^3+5x^2+3x-5$ has three. On the other hand, for our polynomial $f_n$, it is kind of clear that the $-2$ interferes almost nothing in the outputs, but how could I justify it? For example: we can ignore $-2$ because...

You might look into Rouché's theorem and see if it applies here. Cheers

The table seems to be showing the signs of the product $q_9(x) = f_9(x) +2$, not $f_9(x)$ itself with the $-2$. Please also show that when $q_9(x)$ has $+$ sign, it is also $ > 2$ to have $f_9(x)>0$.

Well... without the two every $x = even$ is a root.   At $x=odd$ you have $|f(x)|$ much larger than $2$. so shifting it by $2$ won't cancel any root.

Consider $g(x) = f(x) + 2$. (i.e. ignoring the negative two).  It has roots at every even number.  Between each pair of roots it has a local max/min either negative or positive.  At the odd numbers the value of $g(x)$ will have magnitudes bigger then $2$.  As $f'(x) = g'(x)$ we know $f(x)$ will have local max/min at the same values of $x$.  As shifting the graph by $2$ is smaller then the magnitude of the local extreme the extrema of $f(x)$ will be the same signs as the extrema of $g(x)$.  By ITV there are roots between the extrema. (have to do similar arg. about $x^2+$ not adding extrema.)
